# How to submit a form to 2 different url's

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with 4 inputs:

1. Name
2. Email
3. Voucher
4. Terms

This script is for authenticating into a wifi system. The system only cares about the Voucher value. But i want to record the entire form for records.

Is there any way to have the system submit the form a first time to one url via ajax and then just the voucher as a post ?

I have attached my code below:

Thanks for your help !!

```
<form data-validate="parsley" data-show-errors="true" data-focus="first" name="input" method="post" action="login">
      <input type="hidden" name="by" value="voucher" />
      <input type="hidden" name="page_error" value="en_.html" />
      <div class="voucher-box">
        <!-- Title or Error -->
        <unifi if="has_error">
          <h2 class="error"><unifi error="error" /></h2>
        <unifi else="has_error" />
          <h2><unifi txt="UseVoucher" /></h2>
        </unifi>
        <fieldset class="large-text">
          <p class="form-element">
          <label for="Name" class="fieldname">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" data-required="true" data-minlength="2" data-error-container="div#error" data-error-message="Please enter your name" type="text"  class="textinput" placeholder="John Smith" value="" autocomplete="on" />
          <label for="E-mail" class="fieldname">Email</label>
            <input id="E-mail" name="E-mail" data-required="true" data-type="email" data-error-container="div#error" data-error-message="Please enter your E-mail adress" type="text" class="textinput" placeholder="John.Smith@me.com" value="" autocomplete="on" />

            <label for="voucher" class="fieldname">Voucher Code</label>
            <input id="voucher" name="voucher" data-minlength="10" data-maxlength="10" data-error-container="div#error" data-required="true" data-error-message="Please enter a correct voucher code" type="text" class="textinput" placeholder="00000-00000" value="" autocomplete="off" />
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
      <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="0" data-mincheck="1" data-error-container="div#error" data-error-message="Please accept the terms and conditions before conecting"> <a href="#myModal" role="link" class="link" data-toggle="modal">I accept the terms and conditions</a>
        </label>
  <button type="submit" name="connect" type="submit" value="Connect" id="connect" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Connect</button>
    </form>
  </unifi>
```

Comment: Yes, you can submit the form via AJAX and regular form submit.  However, you need to be careful about the race condition where your regular submission might abort your AJAX call if they are fired too close together (not to mention that you never receive a response from the AJAX call).  Why not fire both form submissions through AJAX?  Or alternatively, use your backend to submit the data from the form to the secondary location.

Comment: I cant submit both via AJAX unfortunately as the voucher needs to go through the system build by the wifi vendor that only accepts POST. Would it be possible to submit the data via AJAX, then wait for the response and then call ?

Comment: You can do AJAX call with `success` function (When the AJAX call completes you can submit Your form to Your second URL using `document.forms["myForm"].submit();`